# Generating a Cognos report using cognos report studio for a SQL query

Tags: sql, cognos

I am a newbie in Cognos. I am trying to create a report using report studio, I have the required package, and I want to create a report using a complex SQL query which has joins between three tables. Can anyone please give a suggestion to start building the report? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[How to write SQL for Cognos reports](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ3R09Oadf8)

FM is to create complex models. If you need a quick-and-dirty report you can specify custom SQL as the tutorial shows.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how the data you see in Report Studio is modelled, typically a tool called Framework Manager is used connect to and model the source tables and views. Framework Manager creates the packages that you see in Report Studio, it can define relationships between entities like tables (if they're not already defined in the source database).

Not sure how to tell from Report Studio if the relationship has been defined properly other than trying to pull over fields from each table into the same Report Studio Query. It is best to talk to whoever designed the Framework Manager model or look at the model itself.